# Sequelize js: create/update with foreign key

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Just want to CRUD and understand how it work.

```
model.wallet.belongsTo(model.users);

model.wallet.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
    return model.wallet.create({
        balance: 300,
        users: {id:1}
    }, {
        include: [ model.users ]
    })
});
```

I tried `include: [ {model: model.users} ]` But still got (NULL)

If you have solution and some example, It should be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the example in Sequelize documentation

> Player.belongsTo(Team); // Will add a ***teamId*** attribute to Player to hold the primary key value for Team.
>
> By default the foreign key for a belongsTo relation will be generated from the target model name and the target primary key name.

Assuming that those models are called `player` and `team`, and the primary key in model `team` is `id`. It means that if you use `belongsTo` on specified model (without any additional option), it will create an attribute with name `<related_model_name><related_model_primary_key>`, so if your user model is called `users` and it's primary key is `id`, then the foreign key created in `wallet` model would be called `usersId`.

---

If you want to create new `wallet` and assign it to user, you need to specify proper foreign key field in `create` attributes

```
model.wallet.create({
    balance: 300,
    usersId: 1
});
```

Comment: It just works with me when I specified the Foreign Key name, like that: model.wallet.belongsTo(model.users, {foreignKey: "usersId"});